# How do I fix "the requested module does not provide an export named 'default'"?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, npm

I'm developing app using JS and Vue.js and get error on line:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

I'm getting this:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module
> '/node_modules/.vite/vue.js?v=6dba2ea6' does not provide an export
> named 'default'

I googled that might be caused by old Vue version, in my *package.json* vue version is 3.2.6, but

```
npm view vue version
```

returns 2.6.14, I tried to upgrade it with Vue CLI

```
vue upgrade
```

but npm command still return 2.6.14

I hope you could help me, what did I wrong or it is not even versions problem? Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem with Vue 3. I updated my node version to 18

Answer (score 21):

The reason it didn't work is that Vue provides a **named** export, whereas you are trying to import it as though it had a `default` export.

To make a **named** import (which you must do with **named** exports), you need to wrap the name of the export you want to import in curly braces, so `{}` around `Vue` like this:

```
import { Vue } from 'vue';
      // ^^^ name of export
```

It will work

The thing you want to do is import vue but it doesnot have a default export function or either the default thing to export is not set in vue module. So you have to select function named vue by adding curly braces.

**If it had** a `default` export function, then your code would have worked and in that case you could write anything in place of `vue` like below:

```
import anyname from 'vue'
```

`anyname` is name whatever you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:-

```
import * as Vue from 'vue';
```

and similarly for different packages:-

```
import * as Vuex from 'vuex';
import * as VueRouter from 'vue-router';
```

As of time of writing:-

```
"devDependencies": {
       ...
        "vue": "^3.2.45",
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually as of Vue 2, in the src/main.js file, we’re bootstrapping the app by calling a new Vue as a constructor for creating an application instance.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from './router'

const app = new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

For Vue 3 the initialization code syntax has changed and is much cleaner and compact

```
import { createApp } from "vue";

createApp(App).use(store).mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the `createApp()` function like this:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

I'm not experienced in Vue.js, but it looks like they no longer export a single object. Rather, a collection of things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using React and got the error because I had forgotten to name one of my files with a `.ts` ending instead of a `.tsx` ending.

I renamed the file `myFile.ts` to `myFile.tsx` and the error disapeared.